# Расположить кнопку, что бы она была между двумя RelativeLayoout

Tags: java, android

Нужно расположить кнопку, что бы она была, как на рисунке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас кнопка неправильно расположена:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас верстка выглядит вот так вот:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorMain"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:subtitleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rvGroupDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fbtIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_white_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorGreyTransparent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etGroupName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgSmile"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fbtIcon"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorMain"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@color/colorMain" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSmile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_tag_faces_24dp"
            android:padding="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fbtIcon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_group_description_icon" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rvParticipants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rvGroupDescription">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fbtDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvQuantity"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorMain" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvParticipants"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_group_description_participants" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvQuantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvParticipants" />


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fbtParticipant"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvQuantity"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_account_grey"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorGreyTransparent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fbtParticipant"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `CoordinatorLayout` и `anchor`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Атрибут `app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"` закрепит `FAB` в `Layout` с `@id/viewA`. 
Атрибут `app:layout_anchorGravity` означает, что кнопку закрепится в правом нижнем углу.

**Результат**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]